# Is it possible to make this navigaion work only on css and remove jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

A bunch of you here were so helpful in assisting me in this smooth drop down navigation system with subcategory 3 however, after looking at it, I was curious if I can get the same effect using only css and remove all jquery. The site that it will be used in was made with pure css and this was the only need for jquery so I wanted to see if I could eliminate the need for that altogether.
This was the fiddle page. I figure using easing would work but not sure how to modify this. Also, the use of "role" in the html wont validate since my site is not html5.

```
<div id="trigger"><a href="#menu" class="menu-link">Menu</a></div>
</div>
<nav id="menu" role="navigation">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Category 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
<li id="Category3"><a href="#">Category 3</a>
    <ul id="extraOptions">
        <li><a href="#">Extra Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Extra Option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Extra Option 3</a></li>
    </ul></li>
<li><a href="#">Category 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Category 5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Category 6</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

**SEE FIDDLE FILE**

http://jsfiddle.net/ApNhK/1/

Comment: Your question, as it stands, is really specific to you. Try and encapsulate the general idea in your question, so that it might be useful to other users.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. In the future ill take that approach. I could have worded the question differently

Comment: It is possible, more or less.  You'll need to be willing to forgo the click events in favor of hover events.  It will take a bit of work, and it's unlikely anyone will flesh out a full solution for you. Try implementing it by writing some new CSS using the `:hover` pseudo class on the elements you are currently applying the click method to in your javascript.  Come back with a new question if you encounter a specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can emulate a `onclick()` in css. If it was `:hover` this would of been possible, why not ?

Edit: I think with `:focus` it might work, I'll check it out, hold on

Edit2: I guess it's impossible. You can have `:focus` to make it look like a click, but it's very limited and you can't make complex nested sub-menus with `:focus` only without javascript.

Comment: You could use the target pseudo-class or :checked for input but they are not supported by all browser notably (ie lower than 9)

Comment: Yeah, hover menu with pure css is possible, but clickable probably isn't. As for :focus, isn't that just for input elements?

Comment: You can emulate a click with `:focus` only if it's attached to the `<a>` tag as shown here http://jsfiddle.net/7RASJ/. However this looks impossible after fiddling for a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts @Wololo I do appreciate that.  I guess limited jquery is fine.  These days almost everything online and mobile is js dependent right

Comment: I think you're thinking of `:active`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, click handlers require JS, I don't think theres any way around it.

Even the "onclick" html attribute is just a lazy way of putting JavaScript inline.

You could have a hovering menu, where the user is required to hover to see the page, but thats not very good UX. I would keep the jquery. I think it looks good, and jQuery is a great library to familiarize yourself with

Comment: so that I understand correctly, in order to click a link to activate a smoothe dropdown like this, jquery is a must correct?

Comment: JavaScript is a must, jQuery is a convenience. But yes, you will want to use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Making a menu (dis)appear on a click can be done with `:target`: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/woestijnrog/9hPZu/3/)

Making a menu with a submenu behave like you want will need some clever use of adjacent/sibling/descendant selectors, if it can be done at all.